# Questions on $\Delta S = \frac{q}{T}$

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

My Thermodynamics book discusses three types of expansions of an ideal gas and the change in entropy $\Delta S$ associated with each expansion, all of which take an ideal gas in a piston from $V$ to $V+\Delta V$:

1. Slow Isothermal: $\Delta S = \frac{q}{T}$, which is sensible since the spatial part of multiplicity $\omega$ increases (momentum part of $\omega$ doesn't increase since $U(T)=3/2 NkT$ for an ideal gas stays constant for isothermal process)
2. Fast Adiabatic: $q=0$ for an Adiabatic Process. But since $S$ is a state function and the endpoints of the process ($V$ to $V+\Delta V$) are the same as above (Slow Isothermal), the change in entropy $\Delta S$ must be the same. Therefore, in this case, $\Delta S > \frac{q}{T}$. Combining these two scenarios, $\Delta S \geq \frac{q}{T}$ in general, where the equality applies for a slow, reversible process and the inequality for a fast one. Conceptually, the author justifies this as "In the expansion into a vacuum, the molecules would strike only stationary walls and hence no energy would be lost from the gas." -- which I do not understand. **The walls are of course moving outwards as the volume expands, so what does he mean?**
3. Slow Adiabatic: This is the one I'm stuck up against. The author argues that since $q=0$ and this is a slow process, we can apply the equality that $\Delta S=\frac{q}{T}=0$. But $S$ is a state function, and the endpoints of this process is the same as the above two. **Thus, why isn't the change in entropy $\Delta S$ the same?**

I have one final question. The book calculates the entropy change when water is heated from $0 °C$ to $70 °C$ by integrating $S=\int \frac{q}{T} dT$ instead of simply calculating $q/T$. **Is this because the change in temperature is significant and cannot be treated to be constant throughout the process?**

Comment: Which thermodynamics book?

Comment: Ralph Baierlein - Thermal Physics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The walls are of course moving outwards as the volume expands, so what does he mean?

It’s assumed that the moving walls are moving so fast—thus the description, **fast** adiabatic—that no or a negligible proportion of gas particles strike them during expansion.

> S is a state function, and the endpoints of [slow adiabatic expansion] is the same as [those of isothermal and free expansion]. Thus, why isn't the change in entropy ΔS the same?

The endpoints aren’t the same. The gas did work without receiving compensating heat, so it’s colder in this example.

> Is this because the change in temperature is significant and cannot be treated to be constant throughout the process?

Yes.

Comment: Finally. Finally I understand. Good lord, thank you.